# Invalid session toked after deleting a user Parse Server Swift

Tags: ios, swift, session, heroku, parse-server

Im running Parse Server on heroku and mLab and I use the following code to delete a user:

```
if PFUser.current() != nil {
        PFUser.current()?.deleteInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToLoginFromSignUp", sender: self)
            } else {
                // Handle error
            }
        })
    }
```

The issue is that after deleting a user if I create a new user I get the error "Invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.14.2)". I understand what a session toked is but I'm not sure how I should be handling it when I delete a user.

Also the error does not cause a crash, it just shows up in the console. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I forgot to log the user out after deleting their account and taking them back to the sigh up view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store the `currentUser` object then log out the user first, and then delete the `currentUser`.

Once you delete the user without deleting the session, the app won't know that the current user doesn't exist any more, the session still remains, therefore you will get a session error after signing up another user.

But if you log out the user first, the current session will also be deleted, then you are free to create a new user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That logic sounds right but I'm not clear on what you mean by Store it. Thanks!

Comment: I realized I forgot to log the user out. Thanks for your help though! It made e go back and take a better look!